# passing text through a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, text, similarity

I currently have python code that compares two texts using the cosine similarity measure.  I got the code [here](http://allmybrain.com/2007/10/19/similarity-of-texts-the-vector-space-model-with-python/).

What I want to do is take the two texts and pass them through a dictionary (not a python dictionary, just a dictionary of words) first before calculating the similarity measure. The dictionary will just be a list of words, although it will be a large list. I know it shouldn't be hard and I could maybe stumble my way through something, but I would like it to be efficient too.  Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "pass them through a dictionary"? What will come out after you "pass them through"?

Comment: To calculate the cosine similarity, the text gets tokenized and stemmed.  I want to take that list of stemmed words and filter out all words that are not in a master list of words.  For example, lets say my dictionary of words did not include any cities.  If the name of a city existed in the text, it would ignore those words when calculating the cosine similarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dictionary fites in memory, use a Python set:

```
ok_words = set(["a", "b", "c", "e"])

def filter_words(words):
    return [word for word in words if word in ok_words]
```

If it doesn't fit in memory, you can use shelve

Comment: I believe last string must be `return [word for word in words **if** word in ok_words]` ?

Comment: Sets are not the same thing as dictionaries (though the implementation is similar).

Comment: Thank you.  This is the "pythonic" way I was looking for.  I'll have to look more into shelve though.

Comment: Andrei: You're right, my bad (note to self: *run* the code before posting)

Answer (score 0):

The structure you try to create is known as **Inverted Index**. [Here](http://www.python.org/workshops/1996-11/papers/InvertedIndex.html) you can find some general information about it and snippets from Heaps and Mills's implementation. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find it's source, as well as any other efficient implementation. (Please leave comment if you will find any.)

If you haven't a goal to create a library in pure Python, you can use [PyLucene](http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/) - Python extension for accessing [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html), which is in it's turn very powerful search engine in Java. Lucene implements inverted index and can easily provide you information on word frequency. It also supports wide range of analyzers (parsers + stemmers) for a dozen of languages.
(Also note, that Lucene already has it's own [Similarity](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html) measure class.)

Some words about similarity and **Vector Space Models**. It is very powerful abstraction, but your implementation suffers several disadvantages. With a growth of number of documents in your index your co-occurrence matrix will became to big to fit in memory, and searching in it will take a long time. To stop this effect **dimension reduction** is used. In methods like [LSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_indexing) this is done by [Singular Value Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition). Also pay attention to such techniques as [PLSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_latent_semantic_analysis), which uses probabilistic theory, and [Random Indexing](http://www.sics.se/~mange/papers/RI_intro.pdf), which is the only incremental (and so the only appropriate for the large indexes) VSM method.

Comment: Since this topic is not about VSM, I won't give more info about it here, but if you need it, please create new topic and post a comment with it here.